# Sorting a form from largest to smallest

Tags: ms-access, vba

I would like to sort records on my form from the largest to the smallest. I am proficient in doing so from smallest to largetst (see code below) but can't seem to find the inverse function.

```
Private Sub Form_Load()

  DoCmd.GoToControl "number"
  DoCmd.RunCommand acCmdSortAscending

End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

One suggestion that may be helpful is to press F2 while in the code window, which will open the Object Browser.

iThen if you paste (or type) the option you know about (adCmdSortAscending) into the search box, and click the 'Search' button, you can drill down to see all of the methods and properties available.

In your case, the next line down will provide you with what you are looking for.